# Publish Asp.net core 3.1 + database + migration

Tags: database, asp.net-core, migration, publish

I have created an application on asp.net core 3.1. I have a database and a migration, but when creating a release, there is no migration in the Publish folder. Need step by step instructions.
I have my own server with a local database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcQ6W.png)

---

Do I need to customize this page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TQY3.png)

Answer (score 0):

1.Try to install MSSMS and connect to your local server. It's needed to manage your local database:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

2.How publish an ASP.NET Core app to Azure with VS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1

3.Deploy local database to Azure portal:
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/deploy-the-database-to-azure-sql#create-a-sql-server

4.Use Azure portal. And try a subscription "trial":
https://portal.azure.com/

I'm waiting for your questions.